# Utilizando elemento KEY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

No meu model, consumo uma view que é construída a base de certas uniões de tabelas, as quais, não possuem nenhum elemento ID auto incrementável.

Meu model exige que eu atribua uma TAG `Key`, porém, como eu não tenho nenhum elemento de valor único, estou obtendo problemas.

Como poderia tirar a necessidade da `Key` ou até mesmo gerar um pseudo ID ?

Comment: Como você retorna essas uniões? Está usando comando SQL ou `linq`?

Answer (score 2):

> Como poderia tirar a necessidade da Key ou até mesmo gerar um pseudo ID ?

A forma mais interessante de fazer isso é unificando todas as estruturas em um *ViewModel* com uma propriedade a mais. Vamos chamar de `linha`.

Ao desenvolver a enumeração que vai para a *View*, faça o seguinte:

```
var listaParaView = new List<ElementoViewModel>();
int i = 0;
foreach (var elemento in PrimeiraLista)
{
    listaParaView.Add(new ElementoViewModel 
    {
        Linha = i++,
        // Coloque os demais elementos aqui    
    });
}

foreach (var elemento in SegundaLista)
{
    listaParaView.Add(new ElementoViewModel 
    {
        Linha = i++,
        // Coloque os demais elementos aqui    
    });
}

return View(listaParaView);
```